# Distinguish design layout for galaxy S3 and galaxy Note

Tags: android, android-layout

How to make layout for galaxy S3 (720x1280 pixels) and galaxy Note (800x1280 pixels).

both are extra high density devices so i need to put two set of images for both devices in same folder drawable-xhdpi.

I dont know how device will detect different different images for both devices because both are from same folder.

please tell me how to make layouts or manage layouts for these two devices in a same application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can distinguish between the devices using the [`-sw<N>dp` qualifier](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support), which discriminates devices based on their smallest-width attribute.

In your case, you will probably want to add a new folder called `drawable-sw400dp`. Drawables in that folder will qualify only for devices with a smallest width of 400dp or greater. Since the Galaxy Note is xhdpi with a smallest width of 800px, it will qualify where the S3 will not.

Comment: its not working..in this case Note and S3 both take layout from this folder.

Comment: Strange. You're sure that both devices are xhdpi?

Comment: (Alternatively, you could target very specifically the Galaxy Note using `layout-large-port-xhdpi-1280x800`, but I strongly discourage your from doing so.)

Comment: layout-sw400dp  this worked for me. but i want to make layout also for galaxy s2(480x800)

Comment: in case of images do i need to put images with different name for both devices or same name with different folders

Comment: I discourage you from targeting specific devices; look them instead in terms of what fits on the screen. If the smallest-width component of a device is 400dp, then you may consider [combining multiple views into one](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html).

Comment: I think in general a good place for you to begin is [reading more about supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).